# Box-Shadow if table cell overflows

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm searching a solution for my Problem:
I have a table, with cells which hide to large content until you hover them (overflow: hidden).

Now I want to add a shadow to the bottom side of an cell if there is some overflow in that cell (content is bigger than cell).

I prefer to solve the problem with pure css - if there is any way.

Here an example how my table looks like - the "much much text" cell should have bottom shadow, but the "less text" not.
http://fiddle.jshell.net/x1f86nxr/1/

*Edit:*
I want to detect automatic what cells are overflowing and add there the shadow - manual adding is easy ;)

Comment: don't think there is a way, the reason luis got jsfiddle 3 rather than 2 was because I had done the same thing as him near enough than realised you probably want it to be expandable ( ie as the table grows not to have to select each one). think only with js is it possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
table tr:first-child td:nth-child(4){
    box-shadow: 0 -10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
}
```

Note: If you want to set dynamic, just add a class to the td, and use this css

```
table tr td.MyClass{
        box-shadow: 0 -10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
    }
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/x1f86nxr/3/)**